# jquery with "event.target" too much recursion

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, recursion

I'm trying to select a radio box when I click an LI. But I get the error "too much recursion".

```
$("li.user_line").click(function(event) {
  if ($(event.target).is('li.user_line')) {
    $(this).children("input[type=radio]").click();
    alert($("input[name=user_chk]").val());
  }
});
```

Comment: Why do you use `$(event.target).is('li.user_line')`? That click function won't work for other elements than `li.user_line`, there is no need to check that.

Comment: Following to what @Oen44 wrote (Which makes total sense), you can check if an element has a class by `.hasClass('className')` and `e.target.nodeName == 'LI'`

Answer (score 1):

That is happening due to event propagation. Every time you click your `li`, you programmatically click an `input` that is its child, which propagates the click back to its parent `li`, which clicks its child, etc.

Why not just toggle the check instead of a click?

```js
$("li.user_line").click(function(event) {
  $(this).children("input[type=radio]").each(function() {
    $(this).prop('checked', !$(this).prop('checked'));
  });
});
```

```css
.user_line {
  padding: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #018bbc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="user_line"><input type="radio"></li>
<li class="user_line"><input type="radio"></li>
<li class="user_line"><input type="radio"></li>
<li class="user_line"><input type="radio"></li>
```

Comment: thank you very much its work but 
when  alert($("input[name=user_chk]").val()); 
give same value

Comment: Just FYI you need to use `prop()` with the logic you have, not `attr()`, as you cannot check the element on the third and successive clicks. Also note that if you want this behaviour you could just use a checkbox and not bother with any JS at all

Comment: i forget input[name=user_chk]:checked its work fine now
thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You get the error because the `input[type=radio]` is a child of the clicked element. Clicking that bubbles up the DOM to the `li`, which then clicks the radio, then then clicks the `li`, which then clicks the radio...

To fix the problem you can simply set the `checked` property of the radio to `true`. There's no need to raise the click event on it.

```js
$("li.user_line").click(function(event) {
  $(this).children("input[type=radio]").prop('checked', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="user_line">
    <input type="radio" />
    Click anywhere here to select the radio
  </li>
</ul>
```

Note that I removed the redundant `is()` method call. Due to the jQuery selector you're using the result will always be `true`. Also note that the effect you're creating here can be achieved in HTML alone using a `label` element.

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to accept an answer if you found it helpful